# The letter " i " in a circle on my chrome browser whats up with that?

Tags: google-chrome

Rebuilt SSD Drive os x, after i reinstalled from my time machine now chrome browser has  the letter " i " in a circle whats up with that?

I clicked on it and it said not private, checked my settings and every seems ok. has any body seen this?

Comment: Hi @GiantTree. You may want to make your knowledge into an answer so people can support you contribution(s).

Comment: @Xavierjazz I added an elaborate answer (I usually comment and later add more in-depth answers).

Answer (score 3):

This is the place where information about the security of your connection to the web server is displayed.

The "i" in a circle means: No encryption, insecure **or** mixed (secure and insecure) content, meaning someone might be able to change the look of a website, but usually not the security of form inputs.

(Sorry, I only have a German screenshot)

[image: Image if the "i" in a circle]

A secure connection features a green lock with accompanied green `https` and maybe even the name of the company, if a EV certificate is used.
Those connections are completely encrypted and each and every individual resource is served through HTTPS, preventing anyone from interfering with the website.

[image: Secure connection]